# how to make dependent dropdown form in django

Tags: django

I have three models and every three models are dependent with each other.while adding the Studentfee model through form when I select the student name then the course price should appear only related to that student's course selection

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    basic_price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    advanced_price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    basic_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    advanced_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Students',blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class StudentFee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=CASCADE)
    total_fee = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=CASCADE) # should dynamically generate in the form based on the selection of student.how ??
    first_installment = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    second_installment = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    third_installment = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.total_fee
```

Comment: Considering adding what is currently happening and what you have tried to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dealing with the problem about what should be computed and what should be stored.
I think you will need another model to manage this, something like 
`CourseSelection`, and cost should be computed at the time of the payment and then stored as `CourseSelectionPayment`

Comment: can you help me to do this please.i am very new to django so it will be very helpful